# rake assets:precompile some error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rake

I created some js file in app/assets/javascripts/ and I ran  `rake assets:precompile`, but rails generated this error.

```
rake aborted!
Unexpected token: operator (>) (line: 14562, col: 9, pos: 545705)

Error<br />
at new JS_Parse_Error (<eval>:1720:22)<br />
at js_error (<eval>:1728:15)<br />
at croak (<eval>:2189:17)<br />
at token_error (<eval>:2196:17)<br />
at unexpected (<eval>:2202:17)<br />
at <eval>:2580:17<br />
at maybe_unary (<eval>:2665:27)<br />
at expr_op (<eval>:2685:45)<br />
```

> at expr_ops (:2692:24)
>      at maybe_conditional (:2696:28)
>      at maybe_assign (:2720:28)
>      at :2734:28
>      at prog1 (:2768:23)
>      (in /home/anybuy/anybuy/app/assets/javascripts/application.js)
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/execj->  > 1.4.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:34:in `rescue in block in eval' <br />
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/execjs-> 1.4.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:28:in`block in eval'
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/execjs-> 1.4.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:80:in `block in lock'<br />
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/execjs-> 1.4.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:78:in`call' 
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/execjs-> 1.4.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:78:in `Locker' <br />
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/execjs-> 1.4.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:78:in`lock' 
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/execjs-> 1.4.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:27:in `eval' <br />
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/execjs-> 1.4.0/lib/execjs/ruby_racer_runtime.rb:19:in`exec' 
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/uglifier-1.3.0/lib/uglifier.rb:100:in >`compile' <br />
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/actionpack-> 3.2.8/lib/sprockets/compressors.rb:74:in`compress' 
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/sprockets-> 2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processing.rb:265:in `block in js_compressor=' <br />
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/sprockets-> 2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in`call' 
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/sprockets-> 2.1.3/lib/sprockets/processor.rb:29:in `evaluate' <br />
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/tilt-1.3.3/lib/tilt/template.rb:76:in >`render' 
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/sprockets->            2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:177:in `block in evaluate' <br />
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/sprockets-> 2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:174:in`each' 
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/sprockets-> 2.1.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:174:in `evaluate' <br />
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/sprockets-> 2.1.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:26:in`initialize' 
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/sprockets-> 2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in `new'<br />
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/sprockets-> 2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:244:in`build_asset' 
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/sprockets-> 2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:89:in `block in build_asset' <br />
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/sprockets-> 2.1.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:19:in`cache_asset' 
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/sprockets-> 2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:88:in `build_asset' <br />
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/sprockets-> 2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:163:in`find_asset' 
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/sprockets-> 2.1.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:56:in `find_asset' <br />
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/actionpack-> 3.2.8/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:23:in`block in compile' 
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/sprockets-> 2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:212:in `block in each_logical_path' <br />
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/sprockets-> 2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:200:in`block (2 levels) in each_file' 
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/sprockets-> 2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in `each' <br />
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/sprockets-> 2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:190:in`each_entry' 
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/sprockets-> 2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:198:in `block in each_file' <br />
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/sprockets-> 2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in`each' 
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/sprockets-> 2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:197:in `each_file' <br />
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/sprockets-> 2.1.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:210:in`each_logical_path' 
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/actionpack-> 3.2.8/lib/sprockets/static_compiler.rb:18:in `compile' <br />
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/actionpack-> 3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:56:in`internal_precompile' 
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/actionpack-> 3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:70:in `block (3 levels) in <top (required)>' <br />
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/actionpack-> 3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:60:in`block (3 levels) in ' 
>      Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile:primary 
>      (See full trace by running task with --trace) 
>      rake aborted! 
>      Command failed with status (1): [/home/anybuy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p392/b...] 
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/actionpack-> 3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:12:in `ruby_rake_task' <br />
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/actionpack-> 3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:21:in`invoke_or_reboot_rake_task' 
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/gems/actionpack-> 3.2.8/lib/sprockets/assets.rake:29:in `block (2 levels) in <top (required)>' <br />
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in`eval' 
>      /home/anybuy/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p392@3.2.8/bin/ruby_noexec_wrapper:14:in `' 
>      Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile 
>      (See full trace by running task with --trace)

here is my app/assets/javascripts/application.js

> // This is a manifest file that'll be compiled into application.js, which will include all the files
>      // listed below.
>      //
>      // Any JavaScript/Coffee file within this directory, lib/assets/javascripts, >vendor/assets/javascripts,
>      // or vendor/assets/javascripts of plugins, if any, can be referenced here using a relative >path.
>      //
>      // It's not advisable to add code directly here, but if you do, it'll appear at the bottom >of the
>      // the compiled file.
>      //
>      //WARNING: THE FIRST BLANK LINE MARKS THE END OF WHAT'S TO BE PROCESSED, ANY BLANK LINE SHOULD
>      // GO AFTER THE REQUIRES BELOW.
>      //
>      //= require jquery
>      //= require jquery_ujs
>      //= require jquery.ui.all
>      //= require twitter/bootstrap
>      //= require twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-transition
>      //= require twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-alert
>      //= require twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-modal
>      //= require twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-button
>      //= require twitter/bootstrap/bootstrap-collapse
>      //= require_tree .

Comment: You're sure there's no bug in your javascript file?  It looks like it's having issue parsing.

Comment: There probably is a bug, but where?  I think the gist of his question is how can he figure out what file/line is causing the error.

Comment: Maybe you can remove a few js files and compile again to limit the possible files with errors..

Comment: Are you using JavaScript templates?